# How to run different functions in loop

Tags: matlab, function, nested-loops, matlab-guide

```
function numbersensors_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles) // edit box to enter the number of sensors
    dat=str2double(get(hObject,'string'));
    newcell = cell(dat,3);
    newcell(:) = {''};
    handles.rnames=cell(1,dat);
    assignin('base','rnames',handles.rnames);
    for i=1:dat
       handles.rnames{i} = strcat('S',num2str(i));
    set(handles.uitable2, 'data',newcell,'RowName',handles.rnames);
    end
    msgbox({'Sensor Connection order';'Light';'Pressure';'Humidity';'Temperature'});
    guidata(hObject, handles);
```

[image]
after entering the num_sensors. the table adjusts the size of uitable.UID is the input of the function to get the respective sensor output
    function plot_on_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles) // toggle button to run the functions

```
tdata = get(handles.uitable2, 'data');
uid=tdata(:,1:2);
assignin('base', 'uid', uid);
y_fp =tdata(:,3);

col=uid((contains(uid(:,2),'Light'))),1);
ill=NaN(100,length(col));
pre=[];
hum=[];
tem=[];
tme=NaN(100,length(uid));
 cnt=0;
   while get(hObject,'value')
         set(hObject,'String','STOP');
   for k=1:length(uid)
           cur=uid{k};
           cnt=cnt+1;
           tme(:,k)=[tme(2:end,k);cnt];
           assignin('base','y',tme);  

        if strcmp(uid((contains(uid(:,2),'Temperature'))),cur)==1         
           temp= get_temperature(cur);
           tem=[tem;temp]; 

    elseif strcmp(uid((contains(uid(:,2),'Pressure'))),cur)==1                   
           press=get_pressure(cur);
           pre=[pre;press];

    elseif strcmp(uid((contains(uid(:,2),'Humidity'))),cur)==1                
           humi= get_humidity(cur);
           hum=[hum;humi];
           assignin('base','hum',hum);   

        else            
           illu=get_illuminance(cur);
           ill(:,k)=[ill(2:end,k);illu]; 
           assignin('base','x',ill);    
           break;
        end    

         plot(handles.axes2,ill(:,1:end));
         legend(handles.axes2,handles.rnames);
         warning('off');
         xlabel(handles.axes2,'Time(sec)');
         ylabel(handles.axes2,'Sensors(Lux)'); 
         pause(1); 

   end

   end          


set(hObject,'String','START')
guidata(hObject,handles);


function p= get_pressure(XYZ) %% Similar functions for get_temperature and get_humidity. din't mention here to save the space
    import com.tinkerforge.IPConnection;
    import com.tinkerforge.BrickletBarometer;
    HOST = 'localhost';
    PORT = 4223;
    UID = XYZ; % Change XYZ to the UID of your Ambient Light Bricklet 2.0
    ipcon = IPConnection(); % Create IP connection
    pr = handle(BrickletBarometer(UID, ipcon), 'CallbackProperties'); 
    ipcon.connect(HOST, PORT); % Connect to brickd
    p= pr.getAirPressure()/1000;
    ipcon.disconnect();

function x= get_illuminance(XYZ)
    import com.tinkerforge.IPConnection;
    import com.tinkerforge.BrickletAmbientLightV2;  
    HOST = 'localhost';
    PORT = 4223;
    UID = XYZ; % Change XYZ to the UID of your Ambient Light Bricklet 2.0
    ipcon = IPConnection(); % Create IP connection
    al = handle(BrickletAmbientLightV2(UID, ipcon), 'CallbackProperties'); % Create device object
    ipcon.connect(HOST, PORT); % Connect to brickd
    x = al.getIlluminance()/100; 
    al.setConfiguration(6,2);
    ipcon.disconnect();
```

In order to develop an GUI for real time data logging from different sensors, I created a toggle button "plot" to plot the data. As, I am using the external supplier micro controller and functions to collect the data using MatLab. The function output is scalar. So, I want to run the functions in loop and get the values into matrix. But my code failed to run through the length of the uid. So, How to fix it? or any suggestions to read the data efficiently are welcome. Thanks

Comment: What have you done to debug the application? What error messages are you getting? What is "the length of the uid"?

Comment: @CrisLuengo: After debugging, I came to know that the k value is not incrementing through the length of uid, remains at 1 and not exiting the get_illuminance function.

Comment: @MaK did you consider the possibility that the "break" might have been triggered, causing the program to exit the loop?

Comment: @Elly I used "break" to exit from the illuminance and continue the loop from the beginning with incremental of 'K'. But, to my surprise, it doesn't work. After using "break", it continously running only the "get_illuminance" function.

Comment: `break` exists the loop. To go back to the beginning of the loop with the next value of `k`, use `continue`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo When I used "continue" the following error occured                                       `Java exception occurred:
com.tinkerforge.TimeoutException: Did not receive response in time for function ID 1

 at com.tinkerforge.DeviceBase.sendRequest(DeviceBase.java:167)

 at com.tinkerforge.BrickletAmbientLightV2.getIlluminance(BrickletAmbientLightV2.java:204)`

Comment: Sounds like this is a totally different issue, though. I don't know anything about tinkerforge, even what it's for. But it tells you it didn't receive a response from the device. Is it connected?